# Ruby & Koala: Why is there a discrepancy between Graph results & Facebook "in app" results?

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using Koala to try and find all photos that I am tagged in, here is the key line of code that I am using:

```
results_page = @grpah.get_connections("me", "photos", {:limit => 1000})
```

This returns 77 results.

However when I log into Facebook, click on "Photos" and "Photos of Jason" - 111 photos are displayed.

Does anyone know why the difference here might exist?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API returns all photos available within the limits of privacy.

The 111 photos are granted for you to see, not necessarily your application. A friend may prevent an application from seeing this by changing their privacy settings.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but if I use the FB Graph Explorer tool I get 81 results using the same access token & the following "me/?fields=photos.limit(500).fields(source)"

Comment: Ideally they should return the same, though you really aren't matching call for call. koala is doing /me/photos?limit=1000 you are doing me/?fields=photos.limit(500).fields(source)

Comment: I have all permissions granted to my app, but the example call in my OP does not return all of the photos which I have uploaded to FB (which are in the 000's) - does FB limit or restrict access to these in some way?